# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.Module from GlassFish server during deploy

Tags: java, web-services, jar, glassfish, web.xml

I'm trying to build a REST webservice and I'm using the `web.xml` build architecture, with **pre-3.0 servlets**. This is my `web.xml`:

```
    <servlet>
        <description>JAX-RS endpoint - JLWS04Serv</description>
        <display-name>JLWS04Serv</display-name>
        <servlet-name>JLWS04Serv</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.psp2.ws4.JLWS04Serv</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ProcessingException</param-name>
            <param-value>com.psp2.ws4.JLWS04Serv</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.hk2.api</param-name>
            <param-value>com.psp2.ws4.JLWS04Serv</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

The problem is that when I try to deploy, the server show this error:

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/Module`

I tried searching for the JAR but I didn't find a single hk2 library that has that directory or the `Module` class.

Comment: Is there a full stack trace in the server log? Also what version of Glassfish are you trying to deploy to?

Comment: the version is 2.0